# Adding more pages and .scala classes in lift framework

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, lift

i am working with lift frame work. i downloaded one sample app from github.com and i am trying to add more lines in it. i have one index.html in src/main/webapp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />   <title>Home</title></head>
<body class="lift:content_id=main">
 <div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
  <h2>Welcome to your project!</h2>
  <p>
<span class="lift:helloWorld.howdy">
  Welcome to your Lift app at <span id="time">Time goes here</span>
</span>
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to add the following line in it

```
<span class="lift:helloWorld.newHowdy">
  Welcome to your Lift app at <span id="newTime"></span>
</span>
```

i wrote the newHowdy method in the helloworld class in the snippet folder. but one error is showing in the browser like , 
 Error processing snippet: helloWorld.newHowdy 
Reason: Method Not Found 
XML causing this error:

how can i solve this? and how can i add more pages and .scala files in the snippet and accessing it from the html pages..thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can have as many classes and html-s you want.

Did you strictly copy-paste the "howdy" method to "newHowdy" ?

Also,  tags should be placed one after another, not inside.
Could you, please, share both the full new HTML code and the snippet code?

Comment: def howdy = "#time *" #> date.map(_.toString)
  def newHowdy = "#newTime *" #>"hii".toString this is my snippet and the       <p>
 <span class="lift:helloWorld.howdy">
   Welcome to your Lift app at <span id="time">Time goes here</span>
 </span>
 <span class="lift:helloWorld.newHowdy">
      Name here <span id="newTime"></span>
    </span>
      </p> is my part of html code